# Xcode 6.0.1 not displaying memory usage

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, ios8, xcode6

I've upgraded to Xcode 6.0.1 from 5.1 and when I'm running my app, I can't see memory usage in debug navigator:

[image]

I'm getting memory warnings. Yes, I could profile my app instruments without debugging, but seeing direct memory usage simply while debugging helps me a lot. How can I re-enable this functionality? I've restarted Xcode, rebuilt my project etc but I still can't see memory usage. The problem is present both when debugging on device or on the simulator. When I click the memory tab, I also get this weird "zeroed out" dashboard:

[image]

Comment: That's actually a table, and you can click on that "Memory" item in that table view. When you do click on it, does anything appear at all?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann the dashboard displays zero bytes for memory usage. I've updated the post now and attached a screenshot demoing the issue.

Comment: Still an issue with Xcode 6.1

Comment: @race_carr exactly. did the answer work for you?

Comment: yes. It's not a great solution, though (because you might want to have Zombie objects turned on for Debugging)

Comment: @race_carr yeah, you are right. I wish Apple fixed it on 6.1. anyway, at least there *is* a workaround.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

I have resolved disabling Memory Guard diagnostic in the Scheme.
From Xcode: Menu Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme... -> Diagnostic Tab -> uncheck all Guard options

**If still doesn't work, try to disable (if enabled) the "Enable Zombie Object" checkbox.**

Comment: I had zombies enabled. I've disabled zombies and now it's working. Thanks.

Comment: all Guard options already unchecked and Zombie Object also unchecked still not working  @fabio

Comment: Yeah!! It was the zombies here too!

Comment: zombie is the key